# question about main vs load

Tags: wiring

Is it legal to have 100 amp main and have a total of 185 amp breakers on one side and 140 on the other?  My daughter had a fire in her attic and was told the main didn't match the load.

Comment: What, specifically, was in the attic that caused the fire?  Where I am from the electrical service usually enters in the basement or utility room, where the main panel is - so an attic fire wouldnt have much to do with the main breaker.  Who told her this?  Fire inspector? Electrician? A random guy on the street?

Comment: I'd almost go so far as to say no fire has ever started from a breaker/fuse being too small. What was on the circuit going through the attic, and what size was its breaker?

Comment: @Dennis, whoever told you that had NO clue what they were talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Its perfectly normal for the main breaker to be smaller than the sum of all the breakers.  This is fine, because its rare that you would turn on your electric stove, dishwasher, hot tub, central air, electric furnace, dryer, fridge, and arc welder all at the same time.

Now, its quite possible that the electric service was undersized for today's use, but that should have tripped the main breaker.  A fire could be caused by a lose connection, which creates resistance, which generates heat.  Or a bad breaker that failed to properly trip.  Or undersized wires, where someone put a larger breaker than the wires were meant for - the modern equivalent of replacing a fuse with a penny.

Aluminum wiring has also been known to cause fires if it wasn't properly installed and maintained.  It can be used safely, but is harder to do right than copper wire.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what they meant when they said "*the main didn't match the load*", but certainly it wasn't because the sum of the handle ratings of the breakers in the panel was more than the main.  More likely, the main was too large for the conductors and/or equipment it was protecting.

Let's say you had a 200 ampere main disconnect, but the conductors or panel it was protecting was only rated for 100 amperes.  The main won't trip until you draw over 200 amperes, but the conductors and/or panel can only handle 100 amperes. So the conductors and/or panel *could* heat up and cause a fire, before the main would trip.